# PHP while command missing first entry

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, phpmyadmin

I am trying to use the while loop to print multiple entries from a MySQL database. Everywhere I do this it is missing the first item on the list and only manages to print from the second one on.

```
<?php
require 'db.php';
$udate = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['date']);
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE date='$udate'");
$user = $result->fetch_assoc();
$_SESSION['file_name'] = $user['file_name'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>View</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nominatorstyle.css">  
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Results.</h2>
            <form action="watch.php" method='POST'><table>
                <?php 
                    if($result->num_rows > 0){
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                            $vid = $row['vid'];                           
                            $source = "uploads/".$row['file_name'];
                            echo "<tr><td>".$row['vid']."</td>
<td>".$row['file_name']."</td>";
                            echo "<td><a href=watch.php?
source=$source>Play</a></td></tr>";
                        }
                    }else{
                    echo "0 results";
                    } 
                ?>
                </table></form>
            <a href="profile.php"><button class="button-block">Home</button></a>
        </div>      
    </body>
```

I'd like it to print all matching criteria.

I'm getting only the entries after the first one.

Comment: So you have a problem in your query. This code looks okay.

Comment: @AdamKozlowski: Eh... Why? Where?

Comment: @panther here is the query `$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE date='$udate'");`

Comment: Any code in between the query and the while loop?

Comment: Maybe you want to change your query ? http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Make sure you have shown us ALL the code

Comment: @RiggsFolly whole page there now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        require 'db.php';
        $udate = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['date']);
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE date='$udate'");

        /*
         This fetch_assoc will get your first row #0 of the query
         next fetch_assoc with your loop on the $result 
         will start as you said from row #1
        */
        $user = $result->fetch_assoc(); //your missing row #0
        $_SESSION['file_name'] = $user['file_name'];
```

Comment: That was it . Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You missed a "}" at the end of your while loop, that might be a problem.. I also changed your >=1 of your num_rows conditions to > 0. Try this:

```
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $vid = $row['vid'];                           
        $source = "uploads/" . $row['file_name'];
        $htmlRow  = "<tr>\n";
        $htmlRow .= "<td>" . $row['vid'] . "</td>\n";
        $htmlRow .= "<td>" . $row['file_name'] . "</td>\n";
        $htmlRow .= "<td>" . $row['vid'] . "</td>\n";
        $htmlRow .= "<td><a href=\"watch.php?source=" . $source . "\">Play</a></td>\n";
        $htmlRow .= "</tr>\n";
        echo $htmlRow;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it's causing `< r>` to print out at the top of the list but still missing the first entry.

the last `<\tr>` should be `</tr>` still only the 2nd entry on.

Comment: You're right for the la </tr> did a typo. edited in the comment.

You gave -1..

Can you show what your query output looks like directly from your mysql database? This should work.

Comment: Just looked at your updated code, the problem is because you're using "$result->fetch_assoc()" twice.

Comment: I didn't give you the negative feedback. Also, I don't have the reputation yet for it to count.